# Unable to get child records after parent record in order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Category table and a stages table. Each category is associated with some stages and  each stage may or may not have child stages.

This is how the SQL schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Category
  (
    Id BIGINT,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Ordinal BIGINT
  )


CREATE TABLE Stages
  (
    Id BIGINT,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    CategoryId BIGINT,
    ParentStage BIGINT,
    Ordinal BIGINT
  )
```

I am trying to write the query so that i get Category, Stage and ChildStages in correct order.

This is what i am trying to get:

```
Category              Stage
-----------------------------
Cat1               Cat1Stage1
Cat1               Cat1Stage2
Cat1               Cat1Stage3
Cat1               Cat1Stage3ChildStage1
Cat1               Cat1Stage3ChildStage2
Cat1               Cat1Stage3ChildStage3
Cat1               Cat1Stage4
Cat1               Cat1Stage5

Cat2               Cat2Stage1
Cat2               Cat2Stage2
Cat2               Cat2Stage3
Cat2               Cat2Stage3ChildStage1
Cat2               Cat2Stage3ChildStage2
Cat2               Cat2Stage3ChildStage3
Cat2               Cat2Stage4
Cat2               Cat2Stage5
```

This is the query i have written which does not give me results in that order:

```
SELECT Category.Name 'Category Name',
        Stages.Name 'Stage Name'
  FROM Category
    LEFT JOIN Stages
      ON Category.Id = Stages.CategoryId
  ORDER BY Category.Ordinal,
        CASE WHEN ParentStage IS NULL THEN Stages.Ordinal ELSE ParentStage END
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8c2d

What am i missing the join order by clause?

Comment: If you `ORDER BY Category.Ordinal,Stages.Name` - won't that give you what you need?

Comment: Will there ever be more than 1 level of child stages?  If so, then you'll need a recursive query to build the correct sort key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem a bit weird at first, but here goes:

- I made a second left join to `Stages` to find the parent of the current stage.
- The order by clause contains:

  - first the Category.Ordinal, as in your query
  - secondly:

    - if the current stage is not a child of another: Stage.Ordinal multiplied by some arbitrary large number (in my case 1000)
    - otherwise, the Ordinal of the parent stage * the arbitrary large number + the Ordinal of the current stage.

This ensures that a parent stage is immediately followed by its children, provided that there are no stages with a number of children greater than the arbitrarily chosen large number.

So, here's how the query looks like:

```
SELECT c.Name 'Category Name',
       s.Name 'Stage Name'
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN Stages s
  ON c.Id = s.CategoryId
left join Stages ps
  on s.ParentStage = ps.Id
ORDER BY c.Ordinal,
case 
  when ps.Id is null then s.Ordinal * 1000
  else ps.Ordinal * 1000 + s.Ordinal
end
```

And here's the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8c2d/27

Answer (score 2):

Below one uses traditional approach with path calculation in recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cteStages AS(
    SELECT *,
        Path=cast(row_number() over (partition by ParentStage order by Ordinal) as varbinary(max))
    FROM Stages
    WHERE ParentStage is null 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.*,
        c.Path + cast(row_number() over (partition by s.ParentStage order by s.Ordinal) as binary(8))
    FROM Stages s
        JOIN cteStages c ON s.ParentStage = c.Id
)
SELECT c.Name [Category Name], s.Name [Stage Name]
  FROM Category c
    JOIN cteStages s ON c.Id = s.CategoryId
  ORDER BY c.Ordinal, s.Path
```